# Delete from database in Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

I have `deleteuser.py` where i need to delete one user, here is the code:

```
# Import modules for CGI handling
import MySQLdb
import cgi, cgitb

# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "", "moviedb" )

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

# Get data from fields
iduser = form.getvalue('iddelete')

# execute SQL query using execute() method.
try:
    cursor.execute("""DELETE FROM user WHERE
         ID = '%s'""",(iduser))
    # Commit your changes in the database
    db.commit()
except:
    db.rollback()

# disconnect from server
db.close()

print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
print
```

I have no error but it doesn`t work.
The database is still the same.

Thank you

Comment: DOn't put code in comments, edit the question.

Comment: You're carefully hiding all possible errors with that catch-all `except` block. **Remove** that so you can see what is actually going wrong. Never, ever, blindly catch and swallow exceptions.

Comment: i have removed try-catch, now i have this error: End of script output before headers

Comment: thank you, that helped me a lot. now i have the answer posted

Answer (score 1):

here is the answer:

```
#!/Python27/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-


# Import modules for CGI handling
import MySQLdb
import cgi, cgitb

# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "", "moviedb" )

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

# Get data from fields
iduser = form.getvalue('iddelete')

# execute SQL query using execute() method.
query = "delete from user where id = '%s' " % iduser
cursor.execute(query)
    # Commit your changes in the database
db.commit()

# disconnect from server
db.close()

print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
print
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your answer. However, don't forget to be specific about what the error was and exactly how you resolved it so that other than benefit from your answer in the future.

Comment: Now, imagine what happens if `iduser` obtained from cgi is `NULL; DROP TABLE user`.